# flutter geolocation take to much time to get location

Tags: flutter, dart

I have flutter app and it has location required so I get user location on splash but it took more than 5 sec to get location and during this time I use to show splash screen so user thinks app is stuck at this time and they close app so can anyone help me how to find how to get location quickly in flutter.

Comment: With some packages, for example [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) you can set a time limit for getting location. But depending on many factors, it might be accurate only after some time.

Comment: Consider not blocking the users on the splash screen, but showing your app, and while location is in progress, display a progress indicator to let them know location is being acquired.

Comment: thanks for your response Peter but my client told me not to show loader so i use getLastknownLocation and if that was empty then I try to get current latlong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many times I make method to get last known location first and if that was empty then I try to get current location with low accuracy it save user time and app run smother

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).